# Jenkins not starting in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I have installed jenkins, it was working fine for a while, builds were working fine.

Suddenly it stopped working. There is nothing in logs

I tried restarting it, no error came up in logs, but still it's not running

```
root@localhost:/home/nilesh# service jenkins restart
 * Restarting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins [ OK ] 

root@localhost:/home/nilesh# service jenkins status
Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is not running
```

Any idea why it's not running ? The machine has 2 GB RAM.

Comment: What do the relevant logs say ? If you can't see anything try increasing the jenkins log verbosity too.

Comment: Only yesterday logs are showing, when jenkins was running, besides restart command says OK, it should have shown some error, Even in syslog nothing is there related to jenkins failure

Comment: Without logs or other relevant info we can only guess. I guess [cosmic rays](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/bofhserver.pl). More seriously, you need to check the jenkins logging options, increase the verbosity and come back with some relevant info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I ran the command manually to run jenkins

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

and it showed No space left on device. Apparently daemon script should have add this error in jenkins logs, but it was showing No error.

Comment: I ran this command and it reinstalled the Jenkins and I lost all earlier setup. Any way to just restart the service without reinstalling it

Comment: This recently happened to me and I found the culprit: my server was hacked and is now mining bitcoins! Check top to see if any mysterious processes are consuming 99% of the processor.

Comment: Is it a good answer to your question? Didn't you ask to run it at startup? Which means runlevel and init.d ...

Comment: be careful, this approach re-install Jenkins.